# Getting statuses and wall pictures through single Graph API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm accessing the Facebook API through the JavaScript API and need the users statuses and wall photos. I'm getting the statuses through /me/statuses, but I do not really have a clue how to include the picture statuses instead of merging the data with the pictures that can be found in the album "Wall Photos". It would be great if that would work with a single request to enable proper pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up an app and get the read_stream permission from the user if you haven't already.
Then you can use me/feed to query all posts on the wall. 
The type of the post won't show up as status but as photo, no matter if it has been uploaded to an album and then shared or directly shared via status update. That is probably why you can't get them through me/statuses.

Comment: I was using /me/feed, but haven't found a way to filter it for specific posts (statuses+photos). Is that correct?

Comment: Well you should be able to get to them by looking at the post type (you'd be looking for status, link or photo) then checking if it comes from the user's id (because other people posting on an user wall also show up as statuses, links or photos)

Comment: To clarify, type: status means message only. When you post a status update with a photo it'll show up as a type: photo. Same thing for links it'll show up as type: link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL to get that info – the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table has a field called `type`, and you can “filter” that for certain types by using the IN operator:

```
SELECT post_id, message, attachment, type FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
AND type IN (46, 247)
```

46 is a status update, 247 is a photo posted to the wall.